# Reducing MODIS MOD16A2 evapotranspiration over a season

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, modis, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reducers

**As per IMD, [there are 4 seasons over India](https://www.imdpune.gov.in/Weather/Reports/glossary.pdf) which are viz**

1. winter (January-February),
2. pre-monsoon (March-May),
3. summer monsoon (June-September),
4. and post-monsoon (October-December).

[**GEE Javascript API is as follows**](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3e12d8831d085473e1f9c61e8aa241a7)

```
var start_year = 2001

var end_year = 2020

var no_of_years = end_year - start_year + 1 

// print (no_of_years)

var etPalette = ['#a50026','#d73027','#f46d43','#fdae61',
  '#fee08b','#d9ef8b','#a6d96a','#66bd63','#1a9850','#006837'];
  
var etPalette_scale_start = 0

var etPalette_scale_end = 4

// Load MODIS imagery and filter ET band from it 

var startDate = start_year+'-01-01'

var endDate = end_year+'-12-31'

var et = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD16A2')  
                .filterBounds(India)
                .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                .select('ET') 
                
var count = et.size()
print("Collection count", count)

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(start_year, end_year);

var byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function(y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
      return et
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
        .sum() // Taking sum for cumulative monthly ET 
        .multiply(0.1) // Scaling to factor
        .selfMask() // to remove all zero values
        .set('month', m)
        .set('year', y)
        .set("system:time_start", ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1).millis());
        });
  }).flatten());
  
print("Collection byMonthYear", byMonthYear)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////// Winter Season /////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// CALCULATING WINTER MEAN
var winter = byMonthYear.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start_year, end_year, 'year'))
                        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,2, 'month'))
                        
                        
// Tanking mean of 20 years of ET for winter months                              
var winter_ET_seasonal_mean_over_whole_study_period = winter.sum().divide(no_of_years)
var daily_winter_ET_seasonal_mean_over_whole_study_period = winter_ET_seasonal_mean_over_whole_study_period.divide(58) // Dividing by no of days in the season to get daily ET
print("Winter Mean ET Raster of 20 Years: ", daily_winter_ET_seasonal_mean_over_whole_study_period)
Map.addLayer(daily_winter_ET_seasonal_mean_over_whole_study_period.clip(India), {min:etPalette_scale_start, max: etPalette_scale_end, palette: etPalette}, 'Winter Mean');


// single zonal value of ROI of ET for winter months over a period of 20 years
var winterMeanValueoverhwoleROI = daily_winter_ET_seasonal_mean_over_whole_study_period.reduceRegion({
                                  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
                                  geometry: India.geometry(), 
                                  scale: 500, 
                                  maxPixels: 1e13
                                  })
                                  
print("Winter Mean ET Value of 20 Years: ", winterMeanValueoverhwoleROI)

Similarly, long term mean can be calculated for other seasons

// ET of winter months of each year
var all_tiles_winterET = winter.map(function(image) { 
                         return image
                         .clip(India)
                         .reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 500); })
                         
                         
//This size should also be 20 i.e 20 rasters for 20 years for winter season,
// How to reduce January and February ET into single raster?
print("All year wise tiles Collection during winter Season", all_tiles_winterET)
```

How to Reduce the MODIS MOD16A2 evapotranspiration for getting annual rasters over these 4 seasons.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want average of every season over the years or 12 mean images (representative of month) over the years?

Comment: Basically I want **1.** average ET of every season, i.e. 4 images of every year of each season i.e 80 images of 20 years . **2.** And 4 images of average ET of every season over the study period of 20 years.

Comment: **Point 2.** ```And 4 images of average ET of every season over the study period of 20 years``` has been resolved here as https://code.earthengine.google.com/3e12d8831d085473e1f9c61e8aa241a7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
var start_year = 2001, end_year = 2020

var et = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD16A2')  
                .filterBounds(India)
                .select('ET') 

// hard-code season start and end
var season_start = ee.List([["winter", 0,2], 
                            ["pre_monsoon", 2,5],
                            ["summer_monsoon", 5,8], 
                            ["post_monsoon", 8,12]]);

// get average ET for every season (mean)
function ETForYear(year) {
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);

  var season_range = season_start.map(function (innerList) {
    var season_name = ee.List(innerList).get(0)
    var n1 = ee.List(innerList).get(1);
    var n2 = ee.List(innerList).get(2);
    var startmonth = startDate.advance(n1, "month");
    var endmonth = startDate.advance(n2, "month")
    var date_range = ee.DateRange(startmonth, endmonth);
    
    var collection = et.filterDate(
      startDate,
      startDate.advance(1, "year")
    );

    collection = collection.filterDate(date_range);
    var reduced = collection.mean()
    return reduced.set("year", year).set("season", season_name);
  });
  
  return season_range

}
                
var ETCollection = ee
  .ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(start_year, end_year).map(ETForYear).flatten())
  
// Point 1
ETCollection.aside(print, "seasonal-average-every-year")

// Point 2 ( get )
ETCollection
  .filterMetadata('season','equals','summer_monsoon')
  .mean().aside(print, "all-time-seasonal-average-ET")
```

The code can be found [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4f9bfad1e93f0b516065379626c8755b)

Comment: Hii Aman, thanks for your time, I had few queries, can you see them here https://code.earthengine.google.com/5c2908b582c853e3dec287e3d2ba3d8a , specifically at line number 26, 49, 67,

Comment: Answered your queries here https://code.earthengine.google.com/90de6e79cbabbf3632f515f3afdc2191  (line 29, 41, 86)

Comment: Thanks @Aman, I have one last query which is mentioned at the end of this https://code.earthengine.google.com/bdfc2af95dd80f781fcb2d261b723acc

Comment: Commented on your query here https://code.earthengine.google.com/e9c7d6a83dc2598d639d1846cdc2ac45