# Retrieving raster images for FLDAS evapotranspiration via GEE and converting units

Tags: google-earth-engine, convert, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using GEE for retrieving FLDAS evapotranspiration data (NASA/FLDAS/NOAH01/C/GL/M/V001) for my study area. For my model, I need one evapotranspiration raster image for each year between 1986 and 2015. **Each pixel in the raster image should have a value for annual evapotranspiration in mm/year**.

The original data comes in kg m-2 s-1, so I used sum() and multiplied by 86400 (number of seconds in a day) and 30.4375 (average number of days in a month) to get the annual values. It would be great if the code were adjusted in a way that not average values for each month are used, but instead the **actual number of days in each month**.

The values I get using my code are however not consistent with the literature for my study area which is why I think there might be an error in the code, possibly related to conversion of the units.

```
// set start and end year
var year = 1986; // Change Year

// make a date object
var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1, 1);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year + 1, 1, 1);

//FLDAS
var fldas = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/FLDAS/NOAH01/C/GL/M/V001').select('Evap_tavg');
var annualEvap = fldas.filter(ee.Filter.date(startdate, enddate)).sum().multiply(86400).multiply(30.4375).clip(StudyArea);

var eViz = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1000,
  opacity: 1.0,
  palette: ["black", "blue", "purple", "cyan", "green", "yellow", "red"]
};

Map.centerObject(StudyArea, 7);
Map.addLayer(annualEvap, eViz, 'AnnualEvapotranspiration_'+year);

// Export AnnualPrecipitation to your drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: annualEvap, 
  description: 'AnnualEvapotranspiration_'+year,
  scale: 11132,
  folder: 'AnnualEvapotranspiration',
  maxPixels:1.0E13,
  region: StudyArea
});
```

[image: Code]

Comment: Did you check this answer: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423858/reducing-modis-mod16a2-evapotranspiration-over-a-season

Comment: Thank you, yes I checked. However, I need a raster image where each pixel represents the annual evapotranspiration in mm for that particular year.

Comment: Yeah but because you believe the problem is related to unit conversion that is the first thing that you could check